# Azure Key Vault Default Encryption?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am reviewing requirements for Azure KeyVault and I would like to store service accounts (username/password) in Azure KeyVault. Is it a best practice to encrypt the secret before storing in Azure KeyVault? Does Azure KeyVault encrypt the secret automatically? (both disk and logical).

Comment: is this a question or are you answering yourself?

Comment: @REI take a look, if you have any more query feel free to share in comment. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: @REI If the answer helpful you could mark it as answer to help others. Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like to store your credential like API-Keys, Certificate, Passwords or anything related to sensitive information ensuring more security right?

Well, As you may know cloud applications and services use cryptographic keys and secrets to help keep information secure. 
For highly sensitive data, you should consider additional layers of protection for data. Encrypting data using a separate protection key prior to storage in [`Key Vault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis) is worthwhile for example.

**Azure Key Vault:**

Azure Key Vault provides safeguards for following keys and secrets.for example, When you use Key Vault, you can `encrypt authentication keys`, `storage account keys`, `data encryption keys`, `.pfx files`, and `passwords by using keys` that are protected by `hardware security modules (HSMs)`.

**Key Vault reduce following problems:**

1. *Secret management*
2. *Key management*
3. *Certificate management*
4. *Store secrets backed by HSMs*
5. *Any Third party sensitive credentials*

You could check for more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis)

**Access Your Key Vaults More securely**

You may need to access your key vault more securely because of its data sensitivity learn more  about [`Secure access to a key vault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault)

**How secret and Certificate collaborate with azure key vault**

Also for key vault **`secret and certificate`** you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates)

**Azure key vault quick start**

Setting up and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using the Azure portal you can quickly start from [`Microsoft official document for azure key vault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal)

**Best Practices:**

As you know `azure key vault` preserves data with encrypted mode so its not necessary to encrypt again but you can for double. Here is some best practice while using `azure key-vaults`

1. Lock down access to your subscription, resource group and Key Vaults
   (RBAC)
2. Create Access policies for every vault
3. Use least privilege access principal to grant access
4. Turn on Firewall and VNET Service Endpoints

For more details you could refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-best-practices)

> **Note:** Now a days `azure key-vaults` become more popular among the big organizations and towards the developer as well to manage large scale
>   of security key , certification and many more. For more details I
>   would recommend to take a look official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis)

If you have any more query feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!